# Selected to cursor on one axis

Tags: snapping, object-mode

I have a problem that I still haven't found an easy solution to, I have ways to handle it but it would be interesting to know how people handles this.

Basically I have a situation where I want to use **snap->selection to cursor** but only in one axis. This is (i believe) only of interest in object mode. so for example I would like to align the center of the active object in the image to the other cylinder's center. to do this I may for example set the cursor to selected for the second cylinder, then select the cylinder I want to align and go selection to cursor, (see picture).

[image]

However it will snap exactly to cursor and if I could I would use this a lot and snap to cursor in just one axis. Sorry I can't seem to make it more clear :P So I'll stop saying the same thing over and over and hope that someone both understand and can help me figure out either a different approach to it or a solution to it.

So what I typically do is to copy the axis value I want from 3D-cursor to Transform location:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: maybe select the object you want to align, then the object on which you want to align, then on the bottom Object > Transform > Align Objects, and play with the options on the bottom of the T menu (example: choose the right axis)

Comment: Thank you @moonboots that is exactly what I was looking for! (if you put it as an answer I will mark it accepted)

Comment: ok, that's done   ;)

Comment: While this (and the accepted question) does solve the OP's problem, it does not address the question title itself, while this is how most people find it on google and such. I suggest renaming to ~ "How to align objects" or searching further for the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the object you want to align, then the object you want to align wih, then, on the header menu choose *Object > Transform > Align Objects*, and play with the options in the *Operator Box* (bottom left of 3D view, example: choose the right axis)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you will want to align objects in a custom orientation.. and unless someone corrects me, I haven't found a way to use the Object > Transform > Align tool to do this.. I always use the following method anyway...

..So set your pivot to 3D Cursor, (or you might choose something else), switch on 'Manipulate Center Points', and scale your selection of objects to 0 along your chosen axis, global, local, or custom.

[image]

If, for example, you had (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd>) created  a custom orientation from an edge, that would be <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to align your objects to the chosen pivot, in a line perpendicular to that edge.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I think this solves a problem I've be en having.